# in my laravel project some datas are not passed to controller from form submit.What could be the reasons?

Tags: laravel

in my laravel project i have made a form with input field name,size,price,etc. My problem is that when i type name in name field datas arenot passed to controller.This is happening only to some specific names.For some other names working fine.And this problem is raised in live in local working fine

below is form blade

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post"
  action="{{route('product')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{csrf_field()}}

<div class="form-group col-lg-6" >
    <label for="select-from">Select Catagory:<span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        @foreach($allcategory as $cat)
            <option value="{{$cat->id}}">{{$cat->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','#category',function(){

            var a = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({

                type:'get',
                url: '{{URL::to('@dashboard@/childcategory-section/submenu-choose')}}',
                data:{'id':a},
                success:function(datas){

                    $("select#submenu").empty();
                    $.each(datas,function(i,data){
                        $("select#submenu").append('<option value="'+data.id+'"> '+data.name+'</option>');
                    });


                }
            });

        });
    });

</script>


<div class="form-group col-lg-6" >
    <label for="select-from">Select SubCategory:<span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <select name="submenu_id" id="submenu"  class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="category">Product Name <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name"   required class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
    <label for="category">Image <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="image" required  class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="category">Old Price <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="old_price"   required class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="category">New Price <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="new_price"   required class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="{{URL::to('ckeditorfull/ckeditor/ckeditor.js')}}"></script>
<div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label for="category">Detail <span class="required" style="color:red;">*</span> </label>
    <div>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="detail" name="detail" ></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'detail');
</script>
<div class="ln_solid"></div>
<div class="form-group ">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="background: #1abb9c;">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

below is controller

```
public function add_action(Request $request){
//dd($request->all());
$datas=new Product();
$this->validate($request,['name'=>'required|unique:products',
'image'=>'required',
'old_price'=>'required',
'new_price'=>'required',
'detail'=>'required',
'total_products'=>'required',
'size'=>'required',
'total_sizeproducts'=>'required']);

$datas->category_id=$request->category;
$datas->menu_id=$request->submenu_id;
$datas->name=$request->name;
$datas->slug=str_slug($request->name);
if($request->hasFile('image')){
$file=$request->file('image');
$filename=time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move(public_path().'/backend/images/products/',$filename);
$datas->image=$filename;
}
$datas->new_price=$request->new_price;
$datas->old_price=$request->old_price;
$datas->rating=$request->rating;
$datas->brand=$request->brand;
$datas->availability=$request->availability;
$datas->total_products=$request->total_products;
$datas->discount=$request->discount;
$datas->detail=$request->detail;
$datas->save();
}
return redirect()->back()->with('success','products added successfully!!!');
}
```

below is route

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'product','prefix'=>'product','middleware'=>'auth'],function (){
   Route::get('/','ProductController@add')->name('product');
  Route::post('/','ProductController@add_action');
});
```

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: update your question and paste your view and controller codes

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The more you show _what_ you've done and _what_ isn't working the more people will be able to help you out!

Comment: You won't be able to get any help with your issue if you don't add (at least) the code for your blade file, the code for your controller and your validation code if you're using a Form request class. Please copy and paste the code into your question, don't just add a screenshot of it :)

Comment: i have updated my question.please anyone help me.this problem  is occuring only to some names.when i submit form nothing happens,just returns back to form without any error message and is not saved to db also.but for most of the names form datas are submitted successfully

Answer (score 0):

Post some code. But you can use dd($request) and you will be able to see the data thats being sent to the controller. Make sure you are using the correct route for that action.